# Geometry nodes and physics?

Tags: physics, geometry-nodes

Can Physics be used in conjunction with Geometry Nodes (Blender 2.92+)? I have a attribute sampled plane using a scaled Cube as the point instance. I would like to apply a gravity (Rigid Body World/Collision) effect, but, nothing happens.

Comment: There is a "make real" node or something like that coming in the works. I'm sure this will be available at one point, but it is not the main focus of the project currently.

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious. Given your high reputation, could you please add a "geometry-nodes" tag to the Blender exchange?  I think that it will get used often...

Comment: Good point ! I'll discuss it with the other users :) As a heads-up generally we don't dive too much into features that are not yet officially released on this site, because it might change drastically from week to week

Comment: Thank you.  I've searched and searched.  This was kind of a last resort.

Comment: In the meantime this is where you can get information on the matter currently : https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes/16108